# Rails app fails to load as soon as i installed capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, bundle, rvm-capistrano

i am trying to deploy my rails application for the first time on vexxhost. i am using github as my Source code management and capistrano.

here is my deploy file

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'capistrano'
require 'bundler'
require 'capistrano-vexxhost'

# Account Settings

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :scm_command, "/home/user/opt/bin/git"
set :local_scm_command,"git"
set :user, "xxxxxxxx"
set :password, "xxxxxxxxx"
set :domain, "domain.com"
set :mount_path,"/home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx"
set :application,"app name"
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :repository, "git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxxxx.git"
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

As soon as i installed gem 'capistrano' gem 'capistrano-vexxhost' i got the following error when trying to load my application locally on my laptop (it was working before installing capistrano).

```
 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:18:in `instance': Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError) 
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/mummy/LagoAds/config/application.rb:6:in `require'
    from C:/Users/mummy/LagoAds/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

NOTE But as i soon as i comment the Bundler.require line from the following code in the application.rb file, it successfully runs but doesn't recognize the gems

```
 if defined?(Bundler)
 # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
 Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
 # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
 end
```

**UPDATE**

when i enter the following code " rake --trace " it also gives me the following error

```
 rake aborted!
 please require the file from withen a capistrano recipe
```

PLEASE I NEED HELP WITH THIS PROBLEM

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you put `capistrano*` gems into the `Gemfile` you need to disable automatic requiring:

```
gem 'capistrano-vexxhost', :require => false
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried what you suggested but i still got the same error. I think the problem has something to do  with BUNDLER because when i comment out the " Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))" line from the application.rd it works but doesn't load the gems.

Comment: did you added this to all `capistrano` related gems?

Comment: yayyy!!! u were right. it works now. But i am wondering, what does "   :require=> false " do and i hope it doesn't affect my deployment to a sheared server.

Comment: it instructs `Bundler` to not automatically require this gems